# Windows 7: how to prevent connecting an USB-memory stick, but allow USB keyboard+mouse

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, security

We don't want a user plug-in USB-memory sticks into a Windows-7 notebook to prevent copying data. But of course, she should be able to use USB keyboard and mouse. Is it possible to tell Windows to prevent any USB-memory stick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a Group Policy named *Prevent Installation of Removable Devices* that can help you.

It can be found here: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Device Installation -> Device Installation Restrictions

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530324.aspx